# Collate Votes by District

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that is taking in a list where each element is a vote in JSON format. I am then building and returning a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{ "District A" : {
    "Match A" : {
        "Candidate A" : {
            0 : 10
            1 : 20
        }
     }
 }
```

Each element in the list could look something like this:

```
{
    "district": "district a",
    "list": {
        "matches": [
            {
                "match": "King",
                "list": {
                    "candidates": [
                        {
                            "match": "King",
                            "candidate": "Candidate 1",
                            "ranking": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "match": "King",
                            "candidate": "Candidate 2",
                            "ranking": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "match": "King",
                            "candidate": "Candidate 3",
                            "ranking": 2
                        },
                        {
                            "match": "King",
                            "candidate": "Candidate 4",
                            "ranking": 3
                        },
                        {
                            "match": "King",
                            "candidate": "Candidate 5",
                            "ranking": 4
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "match": "Queen",
                "list": {
                    "candidates": [
                        {
                            "match": "Queen",
                            "candidate": "Candidate 1",
                            "ranking": 2
                        },
                        {
                            "match": "Queen",
                            "candidate": "Candidate 2",
                            "ranking": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "match": "Queen",
                            "candidate": "Candidate 3",
                            "ranking": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "match": "Queen",
                            "candidate": "Candidate 4",
                            "ranking": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "match": "Queen",
                            "candidate": "Candidate 5",
                            "ranking": 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my code that works:

```
def collate_by_district(votes):
    collated_votes = {}    

    for vote in votes:
        # If the district is in collated_votes
        if vote['district'] in collated_votes:
            for bout in vote['content']['matches']:
                # If the matches is in collated_votes
                if bout['match'] in collated_votes[vote['district']]:
                    # Check if the candidate is in collated_votes
                    for candidate in bout['content']['candidates']:
                        # If the candidate is already in collated_votes update their ranking
                        if candidate['candidate'] in collated_votes[vote['district']][bout['match']]:
                            if candidate['ranking'] in collated_votes[vote['district']][bout['match']][candidate['candidate']]:
                                collated_votes[vote['district']][bout['match']][candidate['candidate']][candidate['ranking']] += 1
                            else:
                                collated_votes[vote['district']][bout['match']][candidate['candidate']][candidate['ranking']] = 1
                        else:
                            rankings = {}
                            if candidate['ranking'] in rankings:
                                rankings[candidate['ranking']] += 1
                            else:
                                rankings[candidate['ranking']] = 1
                            collated_votes[vote['district']][bout['match']][candidate['candidate']] = rankings
                else:
                    match = {}
                    for candidate in bout['content']['candidates']:
                        rankings = {}
                        if candidate['ranking'] in rankings:
                            rankings[candidate['ranking']] += 1
                        else:
                            rankings[candidate['ranking']] = 1
                        match[candidate['candidate']] = rankings
                    collated_votes[vote['district']][bout['match']] = match
        else:
            match = {}
            for bout in vote['content']['matches']:
                candidates = {}
                for candidate in bout['content']['candidates']:
                    rankings = {}
                    candidates[candidate['candidate']] = rankings
                    if candidate['ranking'] in rankings:
                        rankings[candidate['ranking']] += 1
                    else:
                        rankings[candidate['ranking']] = 1
                match[bout['match']] = candidates
            collated_votes[vote['district']] = match    

    return collated_votes
```

It works, and is fast enough, but it just seems rather unwieldy and hard to read. Is there a better way that all these nested if/then statements?

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview.SE. Would you be able to provide a bit more explanation about what your function is supposed to do and how you call it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a better way? Yes, absolutely!

There are two tools that ship standard with Python that you need to  investigate: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

For your code that looks like this:

```
if vote['district'] in collated_votes:
if bout['match'] in collated_votes[vote['district']]:
if candidate['candidate'] in collated_votes[vote['district']][bout['match']]:
if candidate['ranking'] in collated_votes[vote['district']][bout['match']][candidate['candidate']]:
else:
    match = {}
    rankings = {}
```

All this stuff is *exactly* what `defaultdict` is intended to handle: provide a dictionary that, when accessed with a key not currently present in the dictionary, returns a "default" value generated from a no-args factory function.

You can use this with `dict` as the factory function, or `list` or even something clever like a `functools.partial` of `defaultdict` that generates nested `defaultdict`s!

You can also pass `int` as the factory, which constructs an integer (default value = 0) as the default value.

**But wait!** Instead of using `defaultdict(int)` you could also use `collections.Counter`. This implements a bag that counts the number of times each element is added. (It's much like `defaultdict(int)` but with slightly different semantics.)

Which one you use (`defaultdict(int)` or `Counter()`) will depend on your code structure. If you can structure the items as a sequence or generator, the `Counter` might be the best option - it can take a constructor parameter that slurps them all up. If you have to bounce around from one collection to another because of the way your data is structured, the `defaultdict` approach might be best.

Something like this:

```
import functools

from collections import defaultdict

Candidate_factory = functools.partial(defaultdict, int)
Matches_factory = functools.partial(defaultdict, Candidate_factory)
Districts_factory = functools.partial(defaultdict, Matches_factory)

Districts = Districts_factory()

for district in ("District A",):
    for match in ("Match 1",):
        for candidate in ("Leroy",):
            Districts[district][match][candidate] += 1

import pprint
pprint.pprint(Districts)
```

Which outputs:

```
$ python test.py
defaultdict(functools.partial(<class 'collections.defaultdict'>, functools.partial(<class 'collections.defaultdict'>, <class 'int'>)),
            {'District A': defaultdict(functools.partial(<class 'collections.defaultdict'>, <class 'int'>),
                                       {'Match 1': defaultdict(<class 'int'>,
                                                               {'Leroy': 1})})})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am going to read up on everything you provided over the weekend, but this looks like it will help me a lot.